# How do I toggle color writes in SlimDX 11/Direct3D 11 with FeatureLevel 10?

Tags: c#, c++, directx11, slimdx, rendertargets

I'm having trouble setting the `RenderTargetWriteMask` field of a `RenderTargetDescription` struct. I simply want to toggle color writes but every time I try to enable the color writes are changed back to zero. Here is the code:

```
BlendState bs = null, bs1 = null;

try
{
    RenderTargetBlendDescription rtBlendDesc = new RenderTargetBlendDescription()
    {
        RenderTargetWriteMask = ColorWriteMaskFlags.All,
        BlendEnable = false,
        BlendOperation = BlendOperation.Add,
        BlendOperationAlpha = BlendOperation.Add,
        DestinationBlend = BlendOption.Zero,
        DestinationBlendAlpha = BlendOption.Zero,
        SourceBlend = BlendOption.One,
        SourceBlendAlpha = BlendOption.One,
    };

    // default blend state
    bs = BlendState.FromDescription(_device, new BlendStateDescription()
        {
            AlphaToCoverageEnable = false,
            IndependentBlendEnable = false,

        });
    for (int i = 0; i < Constants.MaxSimultaneousRenderTargets; ++i)
        bs.Description.RenderTargets[i] = rtBlendDesc;

    // set default blend state
    _device.ImmediateContext.OutputMerger.BlendState = bs;

    // in debug you will see that the RenderTargetWriteMask field of each render target is set to 'None'...
}
catch (Exception e) { e.Handle(); F.DisposeResource(ref bs); F.DisposeResource(ref bs1); }
```

Update:
I'm not able to set any of the values stored in `RenderTargetBlendDescription`.

Comment: I'm confused; you know that `ColorWriteMaskFlags.All` means [*enable all writes*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476100(v=vs.85).aspx), right? Also, are you saying that `bs.Description.RenderTargets[i].RenderTargetWriteMask` is 0 for all i after that for loop? Or after the assignment of bs to BlendState?

Comment: @JoshPetrie ...i am trying to toggle color writes...my mistake for title...when instantiating a BlendState object the initial RenderTargetWriteMask values are ColorWriteFlags.Zero for each target. My first step is trying to enable all color writes...all values are 0 after for loop

Comment: You probably know, but since `IndependentBlendEnable = false`, 1-7 will be ignored anyway. Just to cover all the bases, have you checked to make sure that `Constants.MaxSimultaneousRenderTargets` is not simply 0?

Comment: @Jon yes the value stored in Constants.MaxSimultaneousRenderTargets is 8. I should also have mentioned that I am using FeatureLevel.Direct3D10 with the Direct3D11/SlimDX11 API.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer in [this thread](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/508846-slimdx-blend-state/) which says:

> States are immutable in D3D10. Once created you cannot modify the
>   properties for the state; the Description is essentially read-only,
>   and we allow the language semantics to enforce that for us (the
>   description is a value type, which is why you cannot modify the
>   properties of the description returned by the Description getter).

I had to enable color writes in the BlendStateDescription before instantiating the BlendState. Code:

```
                    RenderTargetBlendDescription rtBlendDesc = new RenderTargetBlendDescription()
                    {
                        RenderTargetWriteMask = ColorWriteMaskFlags.All,
                        BlendEnable = false,
                        BlendOperation = BlendOperation.Add,
                        BlendOperationAlpha = BlendOperation.Add,
                        DestinationBlend = BlendOption.Zero,
                        DestinationBlendAlpha = BlendOption.Zero,
                        SourceBlend = BlendOption.One,
                        SourceBlendAlpha = BlendOption.One,
                    };
                    BlendStateDescription bsDesc = new BlendStateDescription()
                    {
                        AlphaToCoverageEnable = false,
                        IndependentBlendEnable = false
                    };

                    bsDesc.RenderTargets[0] = rtBlendDesc;

                    // default blend state
                    bs = BlendState.FromDescription(_device, bsDesc);
```